# How do I change a setting for adobe in my active directory?

Tags: shell, active-directory, adobe, automated-deploy

We are having issues with employees' adobe where the save as will just create a grey box with no options and they are forced to restart their adobe acrobat. The solution is to uncheck the "show online storage when saving files" option. But going to every computer and account and disabling them would be a nightmare. Is there anyway we could implement a script of some sort of script for our active directory to automatically disable this setting?

I am not much of a programmer or scripter so any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

•   The registry key path for the option ‘Show online storage when saving files’ is ‘HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\AVGeneral’ and the key for this option is ‘bToggleCustomSaveExperience’ is ‘DWORD’ value which is set when the option in Adobe is checked, i.e., its value is ‘00000000’.

•   So, to uncheck it and remove that option from multiple systems, we can use the following script and deploy it through Group policy on all the systems where Adobe is installed.

```
 ‘ Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\AVGeneral -Name bToggleCustomerSaveExperience -Value 00000001 -Type DWord ‘
```

When you execute the above powershell command on a Windows system with Adobe where the setting needs to be unchecked, it successfully unchecks that option from registry. Also, you need to save the above command in a ‘.ps1’ extension document for it to run successfully and deploy this script through group policy as follows: -

1. Go to your Domain Controller and open the Group policy management console. Then create or edit a GPO (default domain policy).
2. Navigate to ‘Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)’
3. Select ‘Startup or Shutdown’ as per your convenience, select ‘Powershell Scripts’ then select ‘Add’, then browse to the script location, select the script file, then ‘OK’ and save the configuration.
4. Also, set the priority of the GPO accordingly and deploy it across the domain.

•   When this script is deployed and executed successfully, the said setting is automatically disabled, and your issue is resolved.